# How to declare x0 in a matlab function when using it in an interetion method

Tags: matlab, function, input, methods

Here is my code (which is supposed to find polynomial roots using newton method):

```
function z = newton(n, m ,z(0), a)
  b(1)=a(0);
  c(1)=a(0);
  for k=1:1:m
    for j=2:1:n+1
      b(j)=z(k)*b(b-1)+a(j);
    end
    for s=2:1:n
      c(s)=z(k)*c(s-1)+b(s);
    end
    h(k)=-b(n)/c(n-1);
    z(k+1)=z(k)+h(k);
  end
end
```

I cannot call this function because Matlab gives me an error on `z(0)` input argument. `a` is a vector, `n` is the size of the vector, `m` is the number of iterations and `z(0)` is the first x, from which the iteration begins. Can you please help me, maybe there is another way to declare the first x?

I have tried writing:

```
function z = newton(n, m ,z, a)
z(0)=z ;
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: In your function, you will never assign `z(1)`, because `z(k+1)=...` for `k=1,...`. On the other hand, you use `z(1)` in `b(j)=z(k)*...` for `k=1,...`. So, I guess `z(1)=z` should be fine!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not referring here to the logic of your code - the implementation of newton method, i'm just referring to the syntax and rules of Matlab language.

1. You cannot use `z(0)` in Matlab because indexing starts from 1, not 0 (like C, C++ and other programming languages).
   Your `z(0)` needs to be `z(1)`
2. You cannot use `z(index)` in function declaration, you can only put variable names
3. If `n` is the size of the vector `a`, you do not need it as a parameter, just use `n = length(a)` in the function body